# Pass a component as props

Tags: reactjs

I have my card component, in which I need to pass another component into to display unique content for each different card. At the moment, I am passing the example component "Foot" in a ternary operator, but I also need to pass "Patio", "Fence" and "Deck", which relate to specific title props. I hope this all makes sense, here's my code -

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Foot from "../Footing";

const Card = (props) => {
  const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState(false);
  const contentClick = () => {
    setShowContent(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.job}</h1>
      <button onClick={contentClick}>Calculate</button>
      {showContent && <Foot />}
      <hr></hr>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Comment: If you want to interweave content into your `<Card>` component, perhaps it makes more sense to pass it as child nodes? The Card component should be generic enough that it does not need to have knowledge of what is being passed in.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the component as prop to `Card`. React will render the component only if its name is in Pascal case, so renaming the `content` prop to `Content`

**Card**

```
const Card = ({content:Content,job}) => {
  const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState(false);
  const contentClick = () => {
    setShowContent(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{job}</h1>
      <button onClick={contentClick}>Calculate</button>
      {showContent && <Content />}
      <hr></hr>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Usage**

```
import Foot from "../Footing";
<Card content={Foot}/>
```

---

If you want to pass `title` prop to the Foot component,

**Card**

```
const Card = ({content,job}) => {
  return
  <>
  {showContent && content}
  </>
}
```

**Usage**

```
import Foot from "../Footing";
<Card content={<Foot title='foot-title'/>}/>
```

Comment: Hi Shan, does that mean I have to save the other components I wan tot use in Card in an object though? How do I do that?

Comment: Like creating an array of objects and looping through it and render the Card for each object?